# Inner function of redux-thunk is not returning the correct value

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk

I have an action creator like this:

```js
export function fetchData () {
  return async function (dispatch) {
    try {
      const response = await get(some_url)
      dispatch(some_success_action())
      return response
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message)
    }
  }
}
```

Then I dispatch the `fetchData` action and chain it as below

```js
dispatch(fetchData()).then(response => {
  console.log(response)  // logs undefined
})
```

What wrong am I doing? Why does it logs undefined where I expect `response` to be logged returned by `fetchData()`?

Comment: Could you post the code for `get()`?

Comment: Presumably because there was an exception and `return response` did not execute.